# TS import separate type files into a single index.d.ts file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I want to separate component types into individual `index.d.ts` and then import those types into a final `index.d.ts` under my src folder. How can I import these types into a single `index.d.ts` without getting the error `[ts] Import or export declaration in an ambient module declaration cannot reference module through relative module name.`?

**files:**

```
src
 |__components  
 |  |__Text  
 |     |__index.js
 |     |__index.d.ts
 |  |__Button
 |     |__index.js
 |     |__index.d.ts
 |__index.js
 |__index.d.js
```

**src/index.d.ts**

```
declare module "my-module-name" { 
  export { default as Text } from "./components/Text/index.d.ts";
}
```

**src/index.js**

```
export { default as Text } from "./components/Text";
export { default as Button } from "./components/Button";
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use `declare module`. Relative paths don't work there anyway — they can be used only in module *augmentation*, that is when you modify an existing definition.

Start by declaring your components in their respective folders. I used just `React.ComponentType`, but you can be more specific.

**`./src/components/Button/index.d.ts`**

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare const Button: React.ComponentType;

export default Button;
```

**`./src/components/Text/index.d.ts`**

```
import * as React from 'react';

declare const Text: React.ComponentType;

export default Text;
```

Next, create a *barrel file* to re-export your components.

**`./src/index.d.ts`**

```
export { default as Text } from './components/Text'
export { default as Button } from './components/Button'
```

Now your components are accessible both from `./src` and from their respective folders. If we created another catalog called `consumer` in the root of your project, it would have access to your components:

**`./consumer/index.ts`**

```
/**
 * Import the re-exported components from `./src/index.d.ts`:
 */
import { Button } from '../src/';

/**
 * Or import from their respective folders:
 */
import Text from '../src/components/Text';
```

Keep in mind resolving paths in this fashion requires setting `"moduleResolution"` to `"node"` in your `tsconfig.json`.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "moduleResolution": "node"
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear, I have the `index.d.ts` file under src. I just updated my question with my index.js and index.d.ts under src