# How to resolve the error: Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I want to make simple login page using react-hook-form

I get this error:

> Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'

```
import React from 'react';
import { Box, TextField } from '@mui/material';
import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

type InputForm = {
  email: string,
  password: string
}

const Login = () => {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<InputForm>();
  const onSubmit: SubmitHandler<InputForm> = (data: any) => console.log(data)

  return (
    <Box>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <TextField label="email" {...register("email")} />
        <TextField label="email" {...register("password")} />
      </form>
    </Box>
  )
}

export default Login
```

this code give me the following error

```
TS2305: Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'.
    1 | import React from 'react';
    2 | import { Box, TextField } from '@mui/material';
  > 3 | import { SubmitHandler, useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
      |                         ^^^^^^^
```

but when i use simple js file it`s work normally

Comment: which typescript version do you use in your project please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the typescript version you are using in your project could be the source of the error since `react-hook-form` said :

> Important: Typescript ^4.3 above is the recommended version to work
> with react hook form.
> https://react-hook-form.com/ts/

here I tried your code and it is not showing that error
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sea-z5sx9u?file=/src/App.tsx

you can have a look at versions used in `package.json`
https://codesandbox.io/s/compassionate-sea-z5sx9u?file=/package.json

Comment: thank you i,change the version and fix the problem

Comment: happy for you, good luck :)

Comment: Hi there. I am having this problem now. It is giving me the very same error. I have ts ^5.2, and react-hook-form ^7.45. Can anyone help, please? 


Module '"react-hook-form"' has no exported member 'useForm'.ts(2305)

Comment: getting the exact same error. TS 5.3.3 and react-hook-form 7.49.0. Literally copied/pasted their example to try to run it and I get the error.

Answer (score 2):

I having a same issue in my Next Js project.
`tsc -v` says I have typescript version 4.6.0. So I upgrade to latest ~5.3
But still same error. I delete package-lock.json and node_modules folder, re-install and error is gone.

Answer (score 1):

From this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54030107/ts-import-separate-type-files-into-a-single-index-d-ts-file), you need to modify your `tsconfig.json`.

Your moduleResolution in compilerOptions should be `node`. It should look like this below:

`tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    ...  
   },  
  ...
}
```

I am using `"typescript":"5.2.2"` and `"react-hook-form":"^7.46.1"`

Comment: It's works for me, but I just have a doubt about this even reading the post that you mentioned I don't understand exactly why happens and why it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

Install the `@types/react` library:

```bash
npm i @types/react
```

or

```bash
yarn add @types/react
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `use client` to the top of the file where `useForm` is being imported.

[Source](https://github.com/react-hook-form/react-hook-form/issues/11284#issuecomment-1850995149)